# Better way of creating a json payload

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
args = [“f_name”, “l_name”, “age”]

payload = {}
if hasattr(self,”f_name”):
    payload[‘f_name”] = self.f_name 
elif hasattr(self,”l_name”):
    payload[‘l_name’] = self.l_name
elif hasattr(self,”age”):
    payload[‘age’] = self.age
```

I am new to Python, trying to make sense if this is best way to do this, or this can be done in a more Pythonic way?

Comment: what is your expected json output for different inputs? and on that note what is `self` in this case?

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite if last name is entered like l_name=ken, json will be: {'l_name' = 'ken'}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
payload = {arg: getattr(self, arg) for arg in args if hasattr(self, arg)}
```

Comment: If i have nested args, like - classes{"class1": "history", "class2":"maths"}. Can that be covered some how in this statement?

Answer (score 1):

Since the attributes match the names in the `args` list, why not just loop over the whole thing like this:

```
args = ["f_name", "l_name", "age"]
payload = {}
for arg in args:
    if hasattr(self, arg):
        payload[arg] = getattr(self, arg)
```

If you want an even more concise version (although as for readability, it is up for debate), you could go with something like dictionary comprehension:

```
args = ["f_name", "l_name", "age"]
payload = { arg:getattr(self,arg) for arg in args if hasattr(self,arg) }
```

Comment: If i have nested args, like - classes{"class1": "history", "class2":"maths"}. Can that be covered some how in this statement?

Comment: That question is a little difficult to answer because we do not know what `payload` is actually supposed to be. Right now, all this does is convert the attributes of an object into a dictionary, but it only works one level deep. If you want those classes to be converted to a dictionary too, you'll have to rely on recursion.